# ¿En css cómo puedo poner un sidebar uno a la izquierda y otro sidebar otro a la derecha?,

Tags: web, diseño

Esta es mi página web
https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/
Este el codigo html que habia puesto:

```
<section class="main">
    <section class="article">
        <article>
            <h2>Alexandrawp</h2>
            <p>Este es un gran día para ser felíz</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h3>Disfruta</h3>
        <p>Te saluda Alexandra Loor</p>
    </aside>
</section>
```

Este es el código css:

```
header, .main, footer {
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

aside {
        width: 30%;
        background: #ff8000;
        float:right;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Recientemente modifiqué el código html, si se dan cuenta agregué otro `<aside></aside>`

```
<section class="main">
    <section class="article">
        <article>
            <h2>Alexandrawp</h2>
            <p>Este es un gran día para ser felíz</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h3>Disfruta</h3>
        <p>Te saluda Alexandra Loor</p>
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <h3>segundo sidebar</h3>
        <p>esto es una prueba</p>
    </aside>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo puedo modificar los códigos de tal manera que un sidebar esté a la izquierda y otro a la derecha con el contenido en medio?

Comment: podrias usar un framework CSS3 si necesitas facilitar tu trabajo.

Answer (score 4):

Podrias identificar los aside con un nombre de clase, y luego aplicar css a cada clase. Un ejemplo

```css
header,
.main,
footer {
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.de {
  width: 30%;
  background: #ff8000;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.iz{
  width: 30%;
  background: #ff8000;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Alexandrawp</h2>
      <p>Este es un gran día para ser felíz</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <aside class="de">
    <h3>Disfruta</h3>
    <p>Te saluda Alexandra Loor</p>
  </aside>
  <aside class="iz">
    <h3>segundo sidebar</h3>
    <p>esto es una prueba</p>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Como bien ha explicado mi compañero, podrías dar un #id o .class a cada aside y cambiar sus atributos en css, a parte, puedes asociar mas de una class a cada aside de esta forma

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Alexandrawp</h2>
      <p>Este es un gran día para ser felíz</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <aside class="bloque de">
    <h3>Disfruta</h3>
    <p>Te saluda Alexandra Loor</p>
  </aside>
  <aside class="bloque iz">
    <h3>segundo sidebar</h3>
    <p>esto es una prueba</p>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Ahora tendrías una class generica llamada "bloque" y luego los atributos especiales ponerlos en otras class, en este caso "izq" y "der", depende como te quieras organizar, a mi me gusta más así.

```css
header,
.main,
footer {
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.bloque{
  width: 30%;
  background: #ff8000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.de {
  float: right;
}
.iz{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alejandro por tus respuestas, respecto al passing queda así, y no consigo lo que quiero
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrVH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrVH.png)

Comment: el atributo es padding, no passing. Prueba a ponerlo tal y como te pongo aquí. p{ padding: 20px;}

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente cambia el tamaño del width que tienes al 90% por otro más pequeño.
Si tus sidebar tienen de ancho supongamos 10%, tu width debería de ser del 80% para que sumen 100%.

Si no te funciona, prueba a ponerlo de la siguiente manera

```html
<aside class="bloque der"></aside>
<div class="main"></div>
<aside class="bloque izq"></aside>
```

```css
.main{
  float:left;
}
.bloque{
  float:left;
}
```